# How to Read xml file In C#

Tags: c#, xml

this is my xml file

```
<problem>
<sct:fsn>Myocardial infarction (disorder)</sct:fsn>    
<sct:code>22298006</sct:code>
<sct:description>Heart attack</sct:description>
<sct:description>Infarction of heart</sct:description>
<sct:description>MI - Myocardial infarction</sct:description>
<sct:description>Myocardial infarct</sct:description>
<sct:description>Cardiac infarction</sct:description>
</problem>
```

I want to read  Description  section in c#. how can I do this Please help Me ???

thanks

Comment: you can use  XmlTextReader object to read xml file in c#.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it works. This is short and you can read the description easily.
Assume test.xml is the file you want to read . val will contain the value of decription. Please note that since you are using colon in your xml element name , it is important that you associate a namespace in your XML file for sct.

```
XElement  RootNode = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Load("d:/test.xml");   
foreach (XElement child in RootNode.Elements())
{
    if (child.Name.LocalName.Equals("description"))
    {
        string val = child.Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
foreach(XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes){
   string text = node.InnerText; 
}
```

You can read the attribute as

```
string text = node.Attributes["sct:description"].InnerText;
```

You can also refer: [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)

> LINQ to XML provides an in-memory XML programming interface that
>   leverages the .NET Language-Integrated Query (LINQ) Framework. LINQ to
>   XML uses the latest .NET Framework language capabilities and is
>   comparable to an updated, redesigned Document Object Model (DOM) XML
>   programming interface.

Comment: @SarfarazAli:- For that you need to show your effort as to what you have tried.

Comment: @ rahul Tripathi :- Thanks

Comment: Hi Rahul...I have a question ? sct:description...will this be treated as an attribute? I was just trying to see how such elements are parsed by an XML reader and it seems to throw error that sct is an undeclared prefix and hence I am little inquisitive

Answer (score 0):

Reading Xml with XmlReader :

```
   XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlNode));
while (xReader.Read())
{
    switch (xReader.NodeType)
    {
        case XmlNodeType.Element:
            listBox1.Items.Add("<" + xReader.Name + ">");
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.Text:
            listBox1.Items.Add(xReader.Value);
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
            listBox1.Items.Add("");
            break;
    }
}
```

Reading XML with XmlTextReader :

```
 XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader("d:\\product.xml");
 while (xmlReader.Read())
    {
switch (xmlReader.NodeType)
{
    case XmlNodeType.Element:
        listBox1.Items.Add("<" + xmlReader.Name + ">");
        break;
    case XmlNodeType.Text:
        listBox1.Items.Add(xmlReader.Value);
        break;
    case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
        listBox1.Items.Add("");
        break;
}
 }
```